# Where can one download the entire Oxen (Monero Fork) blockchain without syncing from scratch?

Tags: blockchain, monero-forks, loki, oxen

I don't want to sync my oxen network node by waiting for it to connect to peers. Is there a way to just download the entire blockchain directly from a single file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just download it from: https://imaginary.stream/loki/

Just copy the data.mdb file to your ~/.loki folder

As of 2021-March-19, **Loki** project is now called **OXEN** (http://oxen.io). You save the full downloaded blockchain data.mdb file to:

```
/var/lib/oxen/lmdb
```

[image]